# mysql row to column -- grab multiple rows based on value

Tags: mysql

I have a table I want to pull more than one value based on the value in a another column. I use the "WHERE" statement when only one value is needed.  This one needs more than one...

I'd use the usual if I only needed name...

```
WHERE 'wp_postmeta'.'meta_key' = '_name'
```

This is what I'd like to retrieve...

SOURCE TABLE (note the table has a lot of other data I don't need for this)

**meta_key**    ||  **meta_value**

_name       ||  jon doe
_company    ||  ACME Company
_address    ||  123 address

Result I'm trying to make:

**name     ||   company     || address**

jon doe  || ACME Company  ||  123 address

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for the basics of a SELECT statement:

```
SELECT name, company, address from [tablename] where 'wp_postmeta'.'meta_key' = '_name'
```

That will give you those 3 columns for all that match you string for name.

If you need more than that, like, only specific names, use IN not =

```
SELECT name, company, address from [tablename] where 'wp_postmeta'.'meta_key' in ('[thisname]','[thatname]','[othername]')
```

if you're not sure of the name, use a LIKE with wildcards:

```
SELECT name, company, address from [tablename] where 'wp_postmeta'.'meta_key' like '%[name]%'
```

Comment: The name, company, address are row values (not columns) in the source table (wp_postmeta).  It is as though I need to run multiple WHERE statements against the same column and I'm not sure that is possible. I'm trying to turn those rows into column headers in a custom view. I've never used the IN statement... does that help transpose the rows?

Comment: I found this on another thread.  It seems to work, however, it pulls every row and not just the ones with this data.  

How do I eliminate NULL rows?

    SELECT post_id,
      MAX(case when meta_key= '_billing_first_name' then meta_value end) As 'First Name',
      MAX(case when meta_key= '_billing_company' then meta_value end) As 'Company',
      MAX(case when meta_key= '_billing_address_1' then meta_value end) As 'Address'

    FROM wp_postmeta 
    GROUP BY post_id

Comment: You can eliminate NULLS by adding an additional condition WHERE [field] IS NOT NULL.  You can do all sorts of combinations of ANDs and ORs with your WHERE statements that can help filter exactly what you're looking for.